# Git - Accidentally Overwrote Entire Commit History of Remote Repository

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

In an attempt to create a bridge between Git and SVN that allows developers on one project to use SVN and those on another project to use Git, I inadvertantly overwrote the entire git commit history in the remote repository.  Here's the basic work flow that caused the error.

1. Cloned the remote Git repository
2. Followed a series of commands to import the Git repo into SVN.

   a. I tried a variety of methods found via stackoverflow and a several other locations using a local SVN repository as a test.  Most of them failed given the Git repo I was running them against.  However, the set of steps found at http://eikke.com/importing-a-git-tree-into-a-subversion-repository/ appeared to be successful, so those are what I used in the end.

   b. This was only semi-successful. The import into SVN attempted to grab all of the git commit history and import it as SVN commit logs, but failed when it was about 2/3rds of the way through.  The last third was committed into SVN as a single commit.  Further, all of the commit dates were overwritten by the current date and a large portion of the authors were overwritten.  Given that this was in the SVN repo and not the actual Git repo, I wasn't too concerned.
3. Had someone check out the code from SVN, make a change, and commit it.
4. Used git svn to fetch the change
5. Pushed the change to the remote repository.

The end result was that the entire commit history was overwritten with what is now in SVN.  As such, the commit dates and authors were changed and the last 1/3rd of the commit history was lost. Is it possible to recover?

If not, I found a backup of the local repository that I made somewhere in the middle of the process.  It appears to have all of the original commit history.  Is it possible to somehow overwrite the commit data on the remote repository with what I have in this local backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pushed the changes to the remote, you haven't really overwritten anything; it is version control, after all. You should be able to recover the state of the remote by resetting the HEAD to where it was before you did anything. Assuming I'm not misunderstanding what you did, all you really need to do is something like

```
git checkout <SHA-of-old-head>
git add -A
git commit
git push
```

... and you'll be back where you started, although your screw-up will remain in the remote's history. If you don't want that, you need to work on the remote directly and move the HEAD back to where it was.

Comment: As it turns out, svn imported all of the Git commits as separate SVN commits.  The *git svn fetch* retrieved all of these commits and the *git push* pushed them to the remote Git repository as new commits.  This resulted in a plethora of commits that look like the original commits in the log, but are actually duplicates of the originals. This is why I thought the history had been overwritten. Thanks for your post, it led me in the right direction.